# Month and year picker value changes when field is clicked into for second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have some code for a month and year date picker which i got from this site, i have edited the date format (mm/dd/yy) and selecting the values works great, however when i click away from the field and back to it the picker changes the date considerably.

For example, the following invokes the picker with todays date and you click 'Done' which puts todays date into the input field, if you click away and then click the input field again the date picker comes up with December last year, do it again and its december the previous year, etc...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            },
            beforeShow : function(input, inst) {
                var datestr;
                if ((datestr = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
                    year = datestr.substring(datestr.length-4, datestr.length);
                    month = jQuery.inArray(datestr.substring(0, datestr.length-5), $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNamesShort'));
                    $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    .ui-datepicker-calendar {
        display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="startDate">Date :</label>
    <input autocomplete="off" name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
</body>
</html>
```

I'm new to JavaScript so i am struggling to find out exactly where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the following line;

`month = jQuery.inArray(datestr.substring(0, datestr.length-5), $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNamesShort'));`

To this to pick up the right month and it works;

`month = $(this).datepicker('getDate').getMonth();`